# Request timeouts in mssql/msnodesqlv8 when using default Pool size

Tags: sql, sql-server, typescript, msnodesqlv8

I am switching from `mssql` (Tedious) to `mssql/msnodesqlv8`, because we need Windows Authentication support in our `Node.js` service.
However after switching, I run into the following issue.

We have a test that checks if there are no race conditions while getting a new id from the database. To make this operation atomic a `TABLOCKX` is used inside a `transaction`.
The tests starts 100 promises in parallel and checks if 100 unique numbers are generated in the end.

This test succeeds without any issues when using the `mssql` (Tedious) driver.
However, using `mssql/msnodesqlv8`, the test fails with the default pool size of `10`.
*(it fails with request timeout errors)*

When I set the pool size to `4`, the test succeeds. Any bigger pool size will fail.
I tried to reduce the code to the simplest version possible, to make sure this issue is not related to my own code.

- Can you please tell me if I am doing anything wrong ?
- Am I correct to assume that: if this works with `mssql`, it should also work with `mssql/msnodesqlv8` ?
- Could this be a bug in either the `mssql` wrapper or the underlying `msnodesqlv8` driver ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

##### The related table is defined in SQL as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[un_reportlayoutno](
    [NextId] [int] NOT NULL
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

##### The code for the test:

```
const sql: any = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

function getConfig(): config {
    return {
      database: 'EXPR4MSDE_DEV',
      server: 'X10573',
      port: undefined,
      connectionTimeout: 15000,
      requestTimeout: 2000,
      pool: {
        min: 1,
        max: 4
      },
      options: {
        encrypt: false,
        trustedConnection: true,
        instanceName: 'MSDE4EXPR',
        useUTC: false
      }
    };
  }
  async function giveNextId(cp: ConnectionPool): Promise<number> {
    const getQuery = `SELECT un_reportlayoutno.NextId FROM un_reportlayoutno WITH (TABLOCKX)`;
    const updateQuery = (un: number) => `UPDATE un_reportlayoutno SET NextId = ${un+1}`;
    const trans = cp.transaction();
    await trans.begin();
    try {
      const r = await trans.request().query(getQuery);
      const result = r.recordset[0].NextId as number;
      await trans.request().query(updateQuery(result));
      await trans.commit();
      return result;
    }
    catch (err) {
      await trans.rollback();
      throw err;
    }
  }
  test("unique numbers hammering simplified", async () => {
    const cp: ConnectionPool = new sql.ConnectionPool(getConfig());
    await cp.connect();
    const iterations = new Array(100).fill(0);
    try {
      const nrs = await Promise.all(iterations.map(_ => giveNextId(cp)));
      const check = new Set<number>();
      nrs.forEach((n) => check.add(n));
      expect(check.size).toBe(nrs.length);
    }
    finally {
      await cp.close();
    }
  }, 60000);
```

##### Software versions

- NodeJS: `v16.17.1`
- node-mssql: `10.0.2`
- msnodesqlv8: `4.1.2`
- SQL Server: `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR)`